# How to change the infowindow size in geocoding + senchatouch2 mobile?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, geocoding

I am trying to change the size of `infowindow` but it doesn't change.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'point1',            
    //setOptions:{maxWidth : 50,},
    //maxWidth : 50,
    //infoWindowOptions:{maxWidth : 50,},
});
```

All the set options above doesn't work also. 

Any Help please

Answer (score 0):

maxWidth works, you can look at this example from the maps documentation:
[infowindow with max size 200](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple-max)

but I think there's a minimum of about 200px, 
I don't think it's possible to make the window size smaller than that

Comment: Thank you for your help. but do you have any idea to make a new infowindow not base on google map. some thing like to make an panel. I saw some where they did that but base on html not in mobile-app.

Comment: I guess you can listen for a click event on the marker and then try show what ever you want over the map, haven't done it myself